# PHP OO Login and Register

Tags: php, oop, authentication

Let's say I have three classes:

```
User.php
Password.php
Database.php
```

In the interest of learning more OOP, I have some , hopefully simple to answer, questions. Since I still don't fully understand unfortunately.

There are a few things that I want to accomplish. From start to bottom:

- Connect to a database
- Grab the users' password based on the posted username
- Verify the hashed password to the posted password
- Log the user in and redirect them to a certain page

The methods I want to use:

Hashing a password (when a user registers):

```
public function hash($password)
{
    return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
}
```

Grabbing a hashed password from the database:

```
public function hashFromDatabase($username)
{
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->db->prepare("SELECT password FROM users where username = :username");
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));

    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    return $row->password;
}
```

Verifying a password (when a user logs in):

```
public function verify($password, $hash)
{
    if (!password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Right now what I have is the following, purely for testing purposes, in an index.php:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use App\User;

$user = new User;

$user->setUsername('username');
$user->setPassword('password');

echo $user->login();
```

The setUsername and setPassword are simple setters:

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
}
```

And the `$user->login();` is the following:

```
public function login()
{
    $hash = $this->pass->hashFromDatabase($this->username);

    $test = $this->pass->verify($this->password, $hash);

    if($test)
    {
        return "YES";
    }
        return "NO";
}
```

`$this->pass` is from a __construct:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $database = new Database;
    $password = new Password;

    $this->mysqli = $database;
    $this->pass = $password;
}
```

Now, my main question. I know some of my methods are probably not the best right now, but that is not what I am focussing on. I would like to know, in the interest of OO, where to put which methods. Should I simply put all database related stuff in my `Database.php` ? Or should I put the `hashFromDatabase` method in my `Password.php` ? Or can it simply be done both?

And should I be using the three classes that I specified in the top? Or should I simply use an `Auth` class instead of the `User` and `Password`? Or is that simply a matter of taste?

And ofcourse, if you are going to answer, please explain why :) Thanks a lot in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you should work with a layered application. The first thing you need is a model. Have you ever worked with MVC? It's a good start point.

Instead of put all database related stuff inside `Database` class you would create a Repository class which will be responsible for retrieving a given object, say Users (`UsersRepository`).

The repository class would have injected the Database class acting as your database driver. You'd have methods like `getUserByEmail()`, `getUserById()`.

Then you should work on the other layers (Controllers and Views). Even if aren't using a framework you will end-up with some kind of layered application. I'd suggest you to give a try on some framework so that you can better understand those concepts.

You may want to create a service layer also and create an `AuthService` which would have the methods for checking the identity together with the `UsersRepository` and `UsersController`

Comment: Thanks, I've actually got a lot of experience with Laravel, but I still am having a hard time understanding where to put what haha. And in the interest of trying to understand it better, I started writing something from scratch, but I didn't want to go towards a layered application, at least, not really. But I think I will use my laravel experience in order to figure this one out and try to understand it more clearly. Thanks :)